# How to create responsive grid layout in tailwind css?

Tags: html, css, grid, tailwind-css

I have created a grid layout for desktop but, for mobile, it is different.
Below is the photo of desktop version

[image]

I created this layout using the following code:

```
 <div class="grid grid-flow-col grid-rows-2 gap-1 ml-auto justify-center mt-2.5">
            <img src="{{view url='images/icons/ic_mastercard.svg'}}" width="44" height="30" alt="mastercard" loading="lazy">
            <div class="w-[44px] h-[30px] hidden md:block"></div>
            <img src="{{view url='images/icons/ic_maestro-white-bg.svg'}}" width="44" height="30" alt="mastercard" loading="lazy">
            <img src="{{view url='images/icons/ic_gb.svg'}}" width="44" height="30" alt="GB" loading="lazy">
            <img src="{{view url='images/icons/ic_visa.svg'}}" width="44" height="30" alt="visa" loading="lazy">
            <img src="{{view url='images/icons/ic_bancontact-white-bg.svg'}}" width="44" height="30" alt="Bancontact" loading="lazy">
            <img src="{{view url='images/icons/ic_american-ex.svg'}}" width="44" height="30" alt="american exprerss" loading="lazy">
            <img src="{{view url='images/icons/ic_eps-white-bg.svg'}}" width="44" height="30" alt="EPS" loading="lazy">
            <img src="{{view url='images/icons/ic_paypal.svg'}}" width="44" height="30" alt="paypal" loading="lazy">
            <img src="{{view url='images/icons/ic_multibanco-white-bg.svg'}}" width="44" height="30" alt="Multibanco" loading="lazy">
            <img src="{{view url='images/icons/ic_klarna-pink-bg.svg'}}" width="44" height="30" alt="klarna" loading="lazy">
            <img src="{{view url='images/icons/ic_giropay-white-bg.svg'}}" width="44" height="30" alt="Giropay" loading="lazy">
            <img src="{{view url='images/icons/ic_gpay-white-bg.svg'}}" width="44" height="30" alt="google pay" loading="lazy">
            <img src="{{view url='images/icons/ic_alipay-white-bg.svg'}}" width="44" height="30" alt="Alipay" loading="lazy">
            <img src="{{view url='images/icons/ic_applepay-white-bg.svg'}}" width="44" height="30" alt="apple pay" loading="lazy">
            <img src="{{view url='images/icons/sofort.svg'}}" width="44" height="30" alt="Sofort" loading="lazy">
    </div>
```

Now, the issues is, when I switch to mobile, the layout stays the same but, instead, the layout on mobile should be like below photo

[image]

How can I create the layout for mobile like shown in this photo using grid ?

Comment: Please post a [mcve]

Comment: u use the class `grid-rows-2` so it can't expand to 3 rows, so either set `grid-rows-3 md:grid-rows-2` or use a flexbox as krishna suggested

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to replace `grid` layout with `flex` and `flex-wrap` property for your desired behaviour.

---

###### Try the following code:

```
<div class="mx-auto mt-2.5 flex w-96 flex-wrap items-center justify-center gap-1">
  <img src="{{view url='images/icons/ic_mastercard.svg'}}" width="44" height="30" alt="mastercard" loading="lazy" />
  <div class="hidden h-[30px] w-[44px] md:block"></div>
  <img src="{{view url='images/icons/ic_maestro-white-bg.svg'}}" width="44" height="30" alt="mastercard" loading="lazy" />
  <img src="{{view url='images/icons/ic_gb.svg'}}" width="44" height="30" alt="GB" loading="lazy" />
  <img src="{{view url='images/icons/ic_visa.svg'}}" width="44" height="30" alt="visa" loading="lazy" />
  <img src="{{view url='images/icons/ic_bancontact-white-bg.svg'}}" width="44" height="30" alt="Bancontact" loading="lazy" />
  <img src="{{view url='images/icons/ic_american-ex.svg'}}" width="44" height="30" alt="american exprerss" loading="lazy" />
  <img src="{{view url='images/icons/ic_eps-white-bg.svg'}}" width="44" height="30" alt="EPS" loading="lazy" />
  <img src="{{view url='images/icons/ic_paypal.svg'}}" width="44" height="30" alt="paypal" loading="lazy" />
  <img src="{{view url='images/icons/ic_multibanco-white-bg.svg'}}" width="44" height="30" alt="Multibanco" loading="lazy" />
  <img src="{{view url='images/icons/ic_klarna-pink-bg.svg'}}" width="44" height="30" alt="klarna" loading="lazy" />
  <img src="{{view url='images/icons/ic_giropay-white-bg.svg'}}" width="44" height="30" alt="Giropay" loading="lazy" />
  <img src="{{view url='images/icons/ic_gpay-white-bg.svg'}}" width="44" height="30" alt="google pay" loading="lazy" />
  <img src="{{view url='images/icons/ic_alipay-white-bg.svg'}}" width="44" height="30" alt="Alipay" loading="lazy" />
  <img src="{{view url='images/icons/ic_applepay-white-bg.svg'}}" width="44" height="30" alt="apple pay" loading="lazy" />
  <img src="{{view url='images/icons/sofort.svg'}}" width="44" height="30" alt="Sofort" loading="lazy" />
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use grid, but in the below code, the `grid` will always display in 5x3 matrix (since we have 15 images).

```html
 <script src="https://cdn.tailwindcss.com"></script>
<div class="grid grid-flow-col grid-rows-3 sm:grid-rows-2 gap-1 ml-auto justify-center mt-2.5">
            <img src="https://dummyimage.com/720x400" width="44" height="30" alt="mastercard"  loading="lazy">
            <div class="w-[44px] h-[30px] hidden sm:block"></div>
            <img src="https://dummyimage.com/720x400" width="44" height="30" alt="mastercard" loading="lazy">
            <img src="https://dummyimage.com/720x400" width="44" height="30" alt="GB" loading="lazy">
            <img src="https://dummyimage.com/720x400" width="44" height="30" alt="visa" loading="lazy">
            <img src="https://dummyimage.com/720x400" width="44" height="30" alt="Bancontact" loading="lazy">
            <img src="https://dummyimage.com/720x400" width="44" height="30" alt="american exprerss" loading="lazy">
            <img src="https://dummyimage.com/720x400" width="44" height="30" alt="EPS" loading="lazy">
            <img src="https://dummyimage.com/720x400" width="44" height="30" alt="paypal" loading="lazy">
            <img src="https://dummyimage.com/720x400" width="44" height="30" alt="Multibanco" loading="lazy">
            <img src="https://dummyimage.com/720x400" width="44" height="30" alt="klarna" loading="lazy">
            <img src="https://dummyimage.com/720x400" width="44" height="30" alt="Giropay" loading="lazy">
            <img src="https://dummyimage.com/720x400" width="44" height="30" alt="google pay" loading="lazy">
            <img src="https://dummyimage.com/720x400" width="44" height="30" alt="Alipay" loading="lazy">
            <img src="https://dummyimage.com/720x400" width="44" height="30" alt="apple pay" loading="lazy">
            <img src="https://dummyimage.com/720x400" width="44" height="30" alt="Sofort" loading="lazy" class="">
            
    </div>
```

Tailwind Play link  [here](https://play.tailwindcss.com/IcrJ03JbEW?size=416x720)

Comment: I tried it already but, the problem is that on mobile view, in last row, I need the images to be centered. Using grid and 3 rows places the images evenly on each row on mobile view